# Combobox dependientes en python

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

estoy haciendo un formulario con combobox dependientes, pero no puedo pasar el parámetro de un combo a la consulta de otro combo.
¿Cómo puedo tomar el valor de un combo para pasarlo como parámetro a la consulta de otro combo?